# Grab the value from a Dictionary<String, Any> in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Here is some code:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    var dico:Dictionary<String, Any>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dest = "\(String(describing: self.dico?.index(forKey: "adresse"))) \(String(describing: self.dico?.index(forKey: "cp"))) \(String(describing: self.dico?.index(forKey: "ville")))"
        print(dest)}}
```

That's 'dico' it's coming from a segue:

> ["cp": 1000, "id": 4, "loyer": , "ville": bruxelles, "nom": , "ref": garage2, "adresse": 50 rue de spa, "prenom": , "nouveau_loyer": ]

I want to get the value of each element of 'dico' as a string to reuse them after as a long string (it's an address for the Geocoder)
Anyone knows ?

With the previous code I am having this error:

> Optional(Swift.Dictionary.Index(_value: Swift.DictionaryIndexRepresentation._native(Swift._NativeDictionaryIndex(offset: 13))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this combination of *string interpolation*, *optional chaining*, *conditional casting* and the *nil coalescing operator* `??`:

```
let dest = "\(dico?["adresse"] as? String ?? "") \(dico?["cp"] as? String ?? "") \(dico?["ville"] as? String ?? "")"
```

If the value for key `"cp"` is really an `Int`, then do this:

```
let dest = "\(dico?["adresse"] as? String ?? "") \(dico?["cp"] as? Int ?? 0) \(dico?["ville"] as? String ?? "")"
```

Comment: I didn't understand what does those ?? "" but it's working perfectly now. thank you very much !

Comment: The *nil coalescing operator* `??` unwraps an optional if it isn't nil, and in the case that it is nil it uses the default value provided `""`.  In either case, you end up with a non-optional and it doesn't crash.

Comment: aaah ok i got it! thank you for that explanation, appreciated

Comment: Thank you so much .I try to find to this 3 hours more